# worldserver restart if I use ".modify money" command

Tags: docker, azerothcore

I'm using the docker version of AzerothCore rev. ea764812d14a+ 
When I use the command "`.modify money`" the worldserver restart, returning this log message:
`/azerothcore/apps/startup-scripts/simple-restarter: line 70:    76 Segmentation fault`                                                  
`exit code: 139`
`worldserver terminated, restarting...`
This command worked before, any idea to resolve it?

Comment: did you do any customisations? can you try running it with GDB to check where it crashes?

Comment: I do not touch any script/command code, I'll try run it with GDB...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands use **acore_world.acore_string** data, and I had incorrect data in a locale column.

```
entry  content_default     Locale_xxXX
847    ¦ Money: %ug%us%uc  wrong data
```

I delete wrong data, and the problem was resolve.